# Calling a React component based on different states. Need a better solution if possible

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, material-ui

I am using a Modal Component from Material UI and I have to call this component based on the state(useState) I have.

I did something like this -

```
<ModalPopup
   open={deleteRole}
   onClose={handleDeleteClose}
   title={<DeleteConfirmDialog />}
   content={<DeleteRoleContent />}
   footer={<DeleteRoleAction handleDeleteClose={handleDeleteClose}/>}
   maxWidth={'xs'}
/>
```

Here `deleteRole` is a state hook and the modal will get open based on this value (true/false).

I am using another Modal in the same component but with the different set of hook and props.

```
<ModalPopup
   open={open}
   onClose={handleClose}
   title={clientTitle}
   content={clientContent}
   footer={clientAction}
   maxWidth={'xs'}
/>
```

I don't want to use Modal component 2 times, rather I want to use it once and add few conditions to render the correct one at the correct time. I did something like this -

```
<ModalPopup
   open={open || deleteRole}
   onClose={(open && handleClose) || (deleteRole && handleDeleteClose)}
   title={(open && clientTitle) || (deleteRole && <DeleteConfirmDialog />)}
   content={(open && clientContent) || (deleteRole && <DeleteRoleContent />)}
   footer={
      (open && clientAction)
      || (deleteRole && <DeleteRoleAction handleDeleteClose={handleDeleteClose}/>)}
      maxWidth={open ? 'lg' : 'xs'}
    />
```

But not sure if that's the correct way to do it. Any ideas as in how we can do it in more optimized way ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use it twice? If it is another component you are using it, what is the problem?

Comment: I am using it in the same component. Yes I can use it twice. But just want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you use it in * another* component, simply implement `<ModalPopup />` again. If you want to render it various times in the same component, i.e. through a `map()`, you should be careful. This would mean you add the `<ModalPopup />` `n`-times to the `DOM`, only hiding it via the `open` `prop`. A better approach is imho to only add it once to the `DOM` and then set its content (`title`, `content`, `footer`) via the `state`, based on what you have clicked and then showing it. This way, you only add it once to the `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is an oldish question, but still might be helpful to someone.

A way of doing this that I've seen used quite a lot at work is to do something like creating a props object and then spreading that object when calling the modal. Something along the lines of:

```
function getModalProps = () => {
  if(open) {
    return { open: true, onClose:... }
  } else if (deleteRole) {
    return { open: true, onClose:... }
  }
}

... rest of the stuff, then in the render

return <Modal {...getModalProps()} />
```